# WPF use binding to assign static resource

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to use an enum to display a corresponding image. For this I have a value converter that converts an enum to the correct resource name. My resources are defined as follows:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <BitmapImage x:Key="AlarmCat1" UriSource="/Lib.Infrastructure;component/Resources/msg_cat1.bmp" />
    <BitmapImage x:Key="AlarmCat2" UriSource="/Lib.Infrastructure;component/Resources/msg_cat2.bmp" />
    <BitmapImage x:Key="AlarmCat3" UriSource="/Lib.Infrastructure;component/Resources/msg_cat3.bmp" />
    <converters:JamCategoryToImageConverter x:Key="AlarmCategoryConverter" />
</UserControl.Resources>
```

This works:

```
<Image Source="{StaticResource AlarmCat1}" />
```

But this doesn't, the converter is called and the correct value is passed back. What is the correct syntax?

```
<Image Source="{StaticResource { Binding CurrentAlarmItem.AlarmCategory, Converter={StaticResource AlarmCategoryConverter}}}" />
```

For completeness, this is the convert function:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    switch ((AlarmCategory)value)
    {
        case AlarmCategory.Category1:
            return "AlarmCat1";
        case AlarmCategory.Category2:
            return "AlarmCat2";
        case AlarmCategory.Category3:
            return "AlarmCat3";
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I would return the resource in the converter:

```
<Image Source="{Binding CurrentAlarmItem.AlarmCategory, Converter={StaticResource AlarmCategoryConverter}}" />
```

In your converter do something like this:

```
return Application.Current.FindResource("AlarmCat1") as BitmapImage;
```

Set your resources for the complete application with the use of resourcedictionary (app.xaml)

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary1.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

In your Dictionary (Dictionary1.xaml)

```
<BitmapImage x:Key="AlarmCat1" UriSource="bh.jpg" />
```

Because your resources are now defined on applicationlevel, the code will now find your resource and give it back.

Comment: Just deleted my converter... but I am going to try your solution as well. Look more intuitive

Comment: It might not work than. I am sure you can get it to work with a bit of other code, but if the above answer works, I should use that ;-)

Comment: Well, you solution is one line of xaml, the above is 17 lines.... I can move the resource, but should I use the name specified in `User.Control` `BitmapImage` as you can see in my original question? Or the filename?

Comment: The easiest way to make it work with my answer is to change the location of your resources. (I updated my answer)

Comment: No need to make the resource local. I can just add the resource definition from my usercontrol to the resource dictionary as you described and it works. Beauty is that it also works at design time!

Comment: Oh, the Findresource["AlarmCat1"] should be FindResource("AlarmCat1"). Maybe you can update this for future references. Thanks a lot for you help!

Answer (score 8):

You cannot bind the `StaticResource` Key as it is not the `DependancyProperty`. Either you will have to Bind `Source` directly to the enum using `converter` and update the converter code to return the `Bitmap` itself.

Second option will be to used `Triggers` to set the `Source` property depending on the `enum` value.

```
<Image >
   <Image.Style>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
         <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CurrentAlarmItem.AlarmCategory}" 
                         Value="Category1">
               <Setter Property="Source" Value="{StaticResource AlarmCat1}" />
            </DataTrigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
   </Image.Style>
</Image>
```